# Windows : GUI + content flicker when resizing a window (mainly from the left)

Tags: windows-11, intel-graphics, display-driver

I can't remember whether this issue was always present or happened recently.

When I resize a window from the **left side** it flickers on the 'right side' (it's redrawn every x milliseconds).

It happens on both my two monitors, regardless of refresh rates or applications in use. Some behave worse than others, e.g. Microsoft Edge, Visual Studio Code, Sony Vegas Pro or Adobe Photoshop.

It also happens with "embedded windows", like when resizing a floating toolbar inside the Photoshop window.

When I resize the window from the **right side** of some applications everything looks OK, others don't. However, when resizing from the left it always flickers and has visual hick-ups with all applications.

I didn't update anything lately, but do have the most recent Windows 11 (2023H2), UEFI, drivers, etc..

It happens with both "`show window content when dragging`" turned on or off (it slightly improves for some applications while worsens for others).

---

See **[this movie](https://i.imgur.com/lDr3rTv.mp4)** (Edge) and focus on the scrollbar on the right.

It's tearing when resizing and flickering (later on when I select don't show the "`content when dragging`").

The scrollbar appears and disappears when dragging (in real life the behavior is even worse, but due to the framerate of the movie some glitches aren't noticeable).

*I've seen similar issues (on Stack and Reddit), but not quit the same.*

---

**Operating System**

`Windows 11 Home 64-bit`

**CPU**

`Intel Processor`

**RAM**

`32.0GB`

**Motherboard**

`ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. Pro B660M-C D4 (LGA1700)`

**Graphics**

```
PL2792H (1920x1080@75Hz)
PL1780 (1280x1024@75Hz)
Intel UHD Graphics 770 (ASUStek Computer Inc)
```

**Storage**

```
1863GB Samsung SSD 870 QVO 2TB
119GB SAMSUNG SSD 830 Series
465GB Samsung SSD 980 500GB
931GB Samsung SSD 980 1TB
```

**Audio**

`Realtek High Definition Audio`

---

**EDIT**

I did install all video drivers released in 2022 and 2023 in order to see if the issue was always there.

At least with those drivers, the issue still remains.

I also booted up in `safe mode`, disabled most `services`, killed all not necessary processes, etc...

Than I created an empty `guest account` for myself, in order to see if a tool or service was connected to my main account.

Even in a fresh environment, the issue is still there, see [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OSXv.png).

When resizing the (browser) window from the left side, you see the scrollbar jumping over the interface and the minimize / maximize buttons are also redrawn.

This is just a still, the movement is very quick (like, milliseconds).

*The example is from Edge, but it happens in (mostly) all software.*

Comment: Have you installed the latest Intel Graphics drivers (from Intel, not the motherboard vendor)? If not, try that before anything else.

Comment: Yes, I did install the most recent (about a weak old) drivers from Intel. Do you recognize this "tearing resizing" or is is 'just me' ?

Comment: No, not really. If you don't notice tearing when playing videos then there's no problem.

Comment: I'm a graphical designer and move / resize a lot of my windows 10.000 times a day (workflow). For me (visually focused) it's extreme annoying that the GUI flickers (video's are okay, 'though).

Answer (score -1):

A few details are needed here.

1. How old is the system? An aging system might show this issue.

Run any system health scan to see if that is the issue.

2. Are all the cable connections secure?

Check all cable connections to make sure that nothing is too loose.

3. Is the system recognising the correct resolution of the 2 monitors?

Check your settings for that, and ensure the correct monitor matches the profiles in settings.

Remember to check your graphics drivers and **remove all unused drivers to prevent interference**.

Comment: 1. How old? Less than a year, when I bought the system is was on the market for about 2 months (motherboard / CPU / GPU).

2. Connections? Like internet / WiFi / LAN? Yes, they are secure.

3. All drivers and monitors are correct, the issue also appears with a single monitor.

From what I've seen it has something to do with redraw of Windows C# (form elements) and can be solved @ programming level by using "double buffering" (but that doesn't explain my issue).